# map function in R in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I must be missing something, but I don't understand why my map function is not working.

I have a small data set, to which I want to append a ned column - sum of two existing columns:

```
DT <- data.table("columnPred" = c(1,2,3), 
                 "column1" = c(7,8,9), 
                 "column2" = c(44,55,66), 
                 "new_column1" = rep(NA, 3))
```

I wrote my function to sum up:

```
test_map <- function(x){
  
  x$new_column1 = x$column1 + x$column2
  
}
```

and run map:

```
map(DT, test_map)
```

I keep getting errors. What is wrong with my map function? How can I use map to repeat the same function row-wise? is there a better alterntive

Comment: When you use `purrr::map()` in this way, you are trying to apply `test_map` to each column of `DT`.

Answer (score 0):

We do not need `map` for that:

```r
library(data.table)

DT[,new_column1 := (column1 + column2)][]

#>    columnPred column1 column2 new_column1
#> 1:          1       7      44          51
#> 2:          2       8      55          63
#> 3:          3       9      66          75
```

---

However, if we want a map function to get the sum of the two columns, we can do the following:

```r
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

pmap_dbl(DT, ~ ..2 + ..3)

#> [1] 51 63 75
```

Comment: Your second chunk of code is very confusing. `~` in base R corresponds to formula interface. `..2` corresponds in base R to second element of `...`. They seems to have some other meaning in your code.

Comment: You may want to consult the documentation of `pmap` function to check the meaning of `..2` and `..3`, @jangorecki: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowSums`( which would also take care of `NA` elements if present)

```
library(data.table)
DT[, new_column1 := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = column1:column2]
```

-output

```
> DT
   columnPred column1 column2 new_column1
        <num>   <num>   <num>       <num>
1:          1       7      44          51
2:          2       8      55          63
3:          3       9      66          75
```